# Get original transcluded content within angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, transclusion

My goal is to create an `editable` directive that allows a user to edit HTML of any element to which the attribute is attached (see Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/nIrr9Lu0PZN2PdnhQOC6)

This *almost* works except I can't get the original raw HTML of the transcluded content to initialize the text area.  I can get the text of it from `clone.text()`, but that's missing the HTML tags like `<H1>`, `<div>`, etc.  so clicking apply with no edits is not idempotent.

The method `clone.html()` throws an error, `Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined`

```
app.directive("editable", function($rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    templateUrl: "mytemplate.html",
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      content: "=editContent"
    },

    controller: function($scope, $element, $compile, $transclude, $sce) {

      // Initialize the text area with the original transcluded HTML...
      $transclude(function(clone, scope) {

        // This almost works but strips out tags like <h1>, <div>, etc.
        // $scope.editContent = clone.text().trim();

        // this works much better per @Emmentaler, tho contains expanded HTML
        var html = ""; 
        for (var i=0; i<clone.length; i++) {
            html += clone[i].outerHTML||'';}
        });
        $scope.editContent = html;

      $scope.onEdit = function() {
        // HACK? Using jQuery to place compiled content 
        $(".editable-output",$element).html(
          // compiling is necessary to render nested directives
          $compile($scope.editContent)($rootScope)
        );
      }

      $scope.showEditor = false;

      $scope.toggleEditor = function() {
        $scope.showEditor = !$scope.showEditor;
      }         
    }
  }
});
```

(This question is essentially a wholesale rewrite of the question and code after an earlier attempt to frame the question, [Get original transcluded content in Angular directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032347/get-original-transcluded-content-in-angular-directive))

Comment: `clone` is a collection of elements.  Have you been able to inspect it in a debugger?

Comment: Aha! Iterating over them and appending outerHTML is much closer:  `var text = ""; for (var i=0; i<clone.length; i++) {text += clone[i].outerHTML||'';}`.  However, one remaining gap is the HTML of the nested directives is expanded, e.g.  instead of just `<clock></clock>` it shows `<clock><span class="clock"><div class="btn btn-success"><h1>Clock</h1><p>{{time}}</p></div></span></clock>`.   In this example, the clock doesn't transclude content, so the net effect is the same.  I wonder if it's possible to get the original HTML?

Comment: I suspected it might be the case.  Good deal.  The original HTML might be sitting in the $element object in the outer scope. Transclusion is not my strong suit.

Comment: why aren't you wrapping original content in an element with a class that you can use to find it and keep it isolated in one container?

Comment: if it was me would just add textarea/editor on demand like with doubleclcik. Append when needed.

Comment: @user645715 Did you able to figure how to get the 'original transcluded markup'?

Comment: Sorry, no, despite a fair effort.  I then implemented the properties editor using JSON, which mapped directly to jQuery "data-" properties.  (And because the project had lots of nested views, ended up porting it to Backbone.js for simple control over how/when it was rendered)

Answer (score 3):

The `$element.innerHTML` should contain the original HTML.   I am showing that it contains

```
  <div class="editable">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" ng-click="toggleEditor()"></span>

    <div class="editable-input" ng-show="showEditor">
       <b><p>Enter well-formed HTML content:</p></b>
       <p>E.g.<code>&lt;h1&gt;Hello&lt;/h1&gt;&lt;p&gt;some text&lt;/p&gt;&lt;clock&gt;&lt;/clock&gt;</code></p>
       <textarea ng-model="editContent"></textarea>
       <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="onEdit()">apply</button>
    </div>

    <div class="editable-output" ng-transclude=""></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Very helpful.  That contains the template text. Your answer did spark me to add the method `compile(element, attrs)` which has the transcluded HTML in its `innerHTML`.  But it's after Angular expanded it into new DOM elements using the template.  That'll break if any sub-elements have `replace:true` or transclude content themselves.  I suspect there's no way to get Angular to give the HTML from before Angular processed it, and thus the starting content would need to be bootstrapped not via transclusion but passed say via an attribute or ajax.

Comment: This gets into the guts of the digest cycle.  By setting the priority arbitrarily high, you might be able to ensure that it is evaluated first.

Comment: How to get the uncompiled transclude content of an Angular directive if I using `replace:true` with template. it's mean `element` not contain the raw orginal content beacuse `element`is template element not orginal element