# Get transcluded html inside AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive-container (with support for `transclude`), that needs to take the transcluded html exactly as it is and pass it on to a service for further processing.

What is the correct way to get all such transclusion content from within the directive?

Note that the transcluded content is expected to be simple, HTML-formatted text, no events or bindings.

Comment: could you add your code please?

Comment: transcluded HTML doesn't exist. What you are getting is jQuery like object. You can get HTML content from it - but you'll loose all bindings, events etc.
https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/docs/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: @lujcon, I do not need events or bindings from it, just plain HTML as it is. I amended the question with this.

Comment: @pankajparkar, a code showing what? An empty directive declaration with transclude attribute? I don't see the point.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032347/get-original-transcluded-content-in-angular-directive ?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv, that looks about right :) I should have searched better.